# Обособление при уточнении

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

---

**Никто на то, что происходит за пределами США()  обращать внимание точно не станет.**

Ставится ли здесь запятая?

---

**Никто на происходящее за пределами США обращать внимание точно не станет.**

*А в таком предложении?*

*Если не ставится,то как добавить в предложение уточнение "в последнюю неделю" и правильно обособить его?*

Например:

**Никто на происходящее за пределами США в последнюю неделю** обращать внимание точно не станет.

Никто на происходящее за пределами США **в последнюю неделю обращать внимание точно не станет.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первом случае запятая нужна: ***что происходит за пределами США*** — дополнительное придаточное предложение, и поэтому оно обособляется по общим правилам.

Во втором случае запятая не нужна: обстоятельства, не выраженные придаточным предложением или оборотом, никогда не обособляются. Если необходимо провести «смысловую черту», лучше перестроить предложение, например:

> Никто на события, ***происходящие за пределами США в последнюю неделю***,
> обращать внимание точно не станет.
>
> Никто на события, ***происходящие за пределами США***, в последнюю неделю
> обращать внимание точно не станет.